# VBA Filter function with Multiple matches

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get a 0-based single dimensional array using VBA.Filter function.

## A        B        C        D

### CWT1    ATR1    ATR2    ATR3

1        2       3       4
1        1       3       1
3        1       5       7
3        2       2       1
4        5       2       1
6        7       5       4
4        5       2       2
1        3       2       4
1        3       3       7

I want to get a Filtered array based on multiple Match criteria. Filter takes only 1 Match criteria.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim Dict As Object, Dict1 As Object
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim Cell As Range
Dim lRow&, lCol&

Dim Arr

Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set Sht = Sheet1

With Sht
    lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For Each Cell In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lCol)).Cells
        Dict.Add Key:=Cell.Value, Item:=Application.Transpose(.Range(Cell.Offset(1), Cell.Offset(lRow - 1)).Formula)
    Next Cell
Stop
    With Dict
        Set Dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dict1.Add "abal", VBA.Filter(Dict.Item("CWT1"), "3", True, vbTextCompare)
    End With

End With
Stop
End Sub
```

e.g. I want to filter all 1's and 2's in one column (array) using VBA.Filter function, how do i do that?

I also would like to SUM the values of the corresponding columns, when one column is filtered. How can I do this using a dictionary?

P.S: I don't want to use an Autofilter/Advanced filter or any Sheet based operations as I am already pulling sheet/csv data into a Dictionary and would like to do all operations inside Dictionary (or nested Dictionaries), preferably replicate the Advanced filter behaviour.

e.g. If I filter a parent dictionary on multiple criteria, all the child dictionaries (other keys items) should get summed or perform some calculations on them. The reason why I close Filter function is to get rid of using arrays and looping behaviour.

I don't know much about how to replicate this using a class, but surely it can be done with a Custom class + Dictionary, isn't it?

## UPDATE:

I created this multiFilter function from @Chris Nielsen's idea, except it does not use a dictionary and doesnt need to loop multiple times. It loops only through the Matches and still makes use of the filter. Result is concatenated as a string and then finally split and returned back.

This still does not address how i can filter arrays of other keys simulatenously and also do some arithmetic operations amongst them.

### Question:

Can this be implemented in a class, say a Dictionary class that does all the filtering, arithmetic operations amongst its keys (values) etc?

```
Function MultiFilter(SourceArray As Variant, Matches As Variant, Optional Include As Boolean, Optional CompareMode As VbCompareMethod = vbBinaryCompare) As Variant
    Dim x&, Arr, sJoined$

    For x = LBound(Matches) To UBound(Matches)
        Arr = VBA.Filter(SourceArray, Matches(x), Include, CompareMode)
        sJoined = sJoined & VBA.Join(Arr, ",") & ","
    Next x

    sJoined = Left(sJoined, Len(sJoined) - 1)
    MultiFilter = Split(sJoined, ",")

End Function
```

Comment: Kindly invite you  to avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once, you are hopping from one requirement to another newer and broader one with each re-edit. IMO I answered your question, but you won't be able to have all this without any looping. Class implementation sure is possible, but this question is too broad regarding your OP :-) ...I'd suggest  that you ask a new question with more *code input of your own* focussing at one *precise point* where you are confronted with **verifiable** issues (see: "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Since `VBA.Filter doesn't do what you want, I would suggest you roll your own filter function.  Something like this should do it

```
Function MyFilter(dat As Variant, Criteria() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim dic As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = LBound(dat) To UBound(dat)
        For j = LBound(Criteria) To UBound(Criteria)
            If dat(i) Like Criteria(j) Then
                dic.Add CStr(i), dat(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    MyFilter = dic.Items
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

**`Filter` via VBA**

Basically you are asking two questions:

1. "I want to **filter** all 1's and 2's **in one column** (array) using VBA.Filter function, how do i do that?"
2. "I also would like to **SUM** the values of the corresponding columns, when one column is filtered."

There are many or even better ways to do that, but as you prefer **filtering**, I suggest the following steps just to demonstrate a possible approach:

**ad 1)** To overcome the problem that `Filter` allows only one criterium at once, you can read your values in an array, code them via a helper function (see code below) and filter for a single criterium (e.g. "#") as shown in section 3). Then you can transpose a column via `Application.Transpose` and `ApplicationFilter` to allow its use via `Filter`, see section 4).

**ad 2)** As I code the row numbers (temporarily) into the resulting array, you have several possibilities to get values summed up.

*Section 5a)* demonstrates the tricky use of an additional **range filter** together with the worksheetfunction `Subtotal`.

Alternatively *section 5b)* cleans up the array so that you get the result for the chosen column via **`Application.Sum`** based on the filter array.

**Note**

IMO there is **no need** for any *dictionary* using this code. Instead you can sum values up in any of the loops or mentioned sections.

**Example code for one column (e.g. column A)**

This example filters and sums within column A, but you can change that easily for more columns. **Note:** `Application.Index(v, 0, 1)` gets the *first* column out of an 2-dim datafield array, `Application.Index(v, 0, 4)` could get the *fourth* column **D** if you define a broader range, e.g. `Set rng = ws.Range("A2:D" & n)`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DoSomething()
' Declare variables
  Dim a()
  Dim ws   As Worksheet
  Dim rng  As Range, i As Integer, n As Long, v As Variant
' 1) define your sheetname and range (e.g. criteria 1,2 in column A)
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")  ' << change to your sheet name
  n = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & n)                ' assume omitting title row
' 2) set range to a variant 2-dim datafield array
  v = rng
' 3) CODE array items in column A by appending "#"
  For i = 1 To UBound(v)
      If bCheck(v(i, 1)) Then v(i, 1) = v(i, 1) & "#" & i + 1
  Next i
' 4) transform to 1-dim array and FILTER defined code "#" (= row number)
  v = Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, 0, 1)), "#", True, False)
' 5a) get coded row numbers via split function and unhide valid rows
  rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
  For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
      ws.Range("A" & Split(v(i) & "#", "#")(1)).EntireRow.Hidden = False
  Next i
' sum up chosen column via Subtotal function (don't need dictionary)
  Debug.Print "Filtered Sum of column A is " & WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, rng)
' ----------------
' 5b) alternatively
  ReDim a(LBound(v) To UBound(v))
  For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
      a(i) = Val("0" & Split(v(i), "#")(0))
  Next i
  Debug.Print "Filter array sum is " & Application.Sum(a) & vbNewLine & _
              "Result array " & Join(a, ",")
End Sub
```

**Helper function**

This function is called by the above procedure; modify it if there are other conditions to be checked.

```
Function bCheck(ByVal v) As Boolean
' Purpose: Helper function to check conditions v = 1 or v = 2
  If v = 1 Then bCheck = True
  If v = 2 Then bCheck = True
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @chris nielsen. Please see my update post to understand my query.

Comment: Thanks @T.M. Please see my update post to understand my query.

Comment: @sifar785 - You wrote in your P.S.: "The reason why i close Filter function is to get rid of using arrays and looping behaviour." - It won't be possible to avoid that completely. IMO I answered your question. - P.S. It's possible to implement this in your your first code snippet with dictionaries, too if you try.

Comment: i thought it was brief but obvious to anyone when i mentioned i donot want any autofilter/advanced filter options as i am already pulling csv data into a dictionary. Since you still gave me a worksheet-based solution, i had to elaborate to make my point clear. I have not deviated from the OP points.

Comment: I was expecting some possibilities using Dictionaries for doing such filter, arithmetic operations etc; somewhat like what Chris gave me as a solution.

Comment: Sorry, but IMO you are deviating from your OP regarding VBA filtering with multiple matches = "how do I do that?" ; my suggestion would be to formulate another question :-)

Comment: You can omit the worksheet related section 5a) completely and you'll find the working alternative in 5b). - Further hint using arrays in dictionaries: you first need to copy them out into a temp variable before you can do anything with them  (e.g. adding items).

Comment: i know the arrays for each keys are read-only in dictionaries and need the assistance of temporary variable for replacing values. Also, my 2 original questions still stick: 1] how do i filter a dictionary key on multiple filters 2] that should filter other dictionary key arrays also?